# How can I enter a list in a cell of an org-mode table?

Tags: org-mode

Can I enter an org-mode list in a cell of an org-mode table?

Comment: org-mode lists in the actual sense are not supported. But, you can use calc. For an instance you can input a vector `[1 2 3]` within a table cell and calculate its sum by `vsum(...)`. (Replace the ellipsis by the table cell address.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Org does not support any list in a table cell.

Answer (score 1):

*Org-mode does not support list inside table, so this is merely an alternative approach*

When I faced  this problem, I use this approach

- use internal link from org-table to org-list

e.g: my age and plans at every age

```
|  [[1]] |  [[2]] |  [[3]] |  [[4]] |  [[5]] |
|----+----+----+----+----|
|  [[6]] |  [[7]] |  [[8]] |  [[9]] | [[10]] |
|----+----+----+----+----|
| [[11]] | [[12]] | [[13]] | [[14]] | [[15]] |
|----+----+----+----+----|
| [[16]] | [[17]] | [[18]] | [[19]] | [[20]] |
|----+----+----+----+----|
| [[21]] | [[22]] | [[23]] | [[24]] | [[25]] |
|----+----+----+----+----|


** 1
- foo
- bar
  - baz

** 2

** 3

** 4

** 5

** 6
```

With this approach I have complete feature of org-mode list and table all, so I can use anything I want with plain text.

[image: Life table]